# Is there any implementation of Flickr Context Similarity or Normalized Google Distance?

Tags: tags, semantics, flickr

I need to measure semantic similarity between two tags

The best way is to use the FCS (Flickr Context Similarity) as my tags are associated with images crawled from Flickr .

This document show how to compute it theoretically 
http://www.ee.columbia.edu/ln/dvmm/researchProjects/MultimediaIndexing/CBVS_FCS/CBVS_FCS.htm

Is there any implementation in java or any other language ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of the Normalized Google Distance here:https://code.google.com/p/ext-c/source/browse/trunk/src/nz/ac/vuw/ecs/kcassell/similarity/GoogleDistanceCalculator.java?r=28

Use the result as input to the Gaussian distribution and that is the FCS (as it says in the link you posted)

Comment: I've already tried it but the problem is how to get the number of hit for each word/synset :google search engine is deprecated and yahoo search api is not free

Comment: Why don't you use flickr api since you want to measure tag similarity from images crawled from flickr? As far as i know flickr api has no limits. Also, keep in mind this, that might give you better results http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/76616/2008_ACMMM_FlickrDistance.pdf